# How to make a copy of pointer value in c++ and prevent crash

Tags: c++, pointers, directx-11

I have a function that return the pixel color of a specific X, Y coordinate of the screen using DirectX 11.

The function use the method "AcquireNextFrame" that unfortunately fail (DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT) if the current frame is equal to the previous.

So some users suggest to do a copy of "IDXGIOutputDuplication" value but after some attempts I see begin instable like other users say in these cases.

For this reason I have tried to do a "backup copy" of the other parts of my code using these variables: "gpuTexPrevious" and "cpuTexPrevious":

```
ID3D11Texture2D* gpuTexPrevious = nullptr;
ID3D11Texture2D* cpuTexPrevious = nullptr;

RGBTRIPLE CaptureNext(int X, int Y) {

    bool NewFrame;

    RGBTRIPLE rgb;

    rgb.rgbtBlue = 0;
    rgb.rgbtGreen = 0;
    rgb.rgbtBlue = 0;

    HRESULT hr;

    IDXGIResource* deskRes = nullptr;
    DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO frameInfo;
    
    hr = DeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(0, &frameInfo, &deskRes);
    if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        LF::Log_Update(" DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT");

        NewFrame = false;
    }
    else
        NewFrame = true;

    ID3D11Texture2D* gpuTex = nullptr;
    ID3D11Texture2D* cpuTex = nullptr;

    if (NewFrame)
    {
        hr = deskRes->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&gpuTex);
        deskRes->Release();
        deskRes = nullptr;
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            // not expected
            return rgb;
        }

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
        gpuTex->GetDesc(&desc);
        desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
        desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
        desc.BindFlags = 0;
        desc.MiscFlags = 0; // D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GDI_COMPATIBLE ?
        hr = D3DDeviceTest->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &cpuTex);
        memcpy(&cpuTexPrevious, &cpuTex, sizeof(ID3D11Texture2D));
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(&gpuTex, &gpuTexPrevious, sizeof(ID3D11Texture2D));
        memcpy(&cpuTex, &cpuTexPrevious, sizeof(ID3D11Texture2D));
    }

    D3D11_BOX srcBox;
    srcBox.left = X;
    srcBox.right = X + 1;
    srcBox.bottom = Y + 1;
    srcBox.top = Y;
    srcBox.front = 0;
    srcBox.back = 1;

    D3DDeviceContextTest->CopySubresourceRegion(cpuTex, 0, 0, 0, 0, gpuTex, 0, &srcBox);

    memcpy(&gpuTexPrevious, &gpuTex,sizeof(ID3D11Texture2D));

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE sr;
    
    // crash here when NewFrame = false
    hr = D3DDeviceContextTest->Map(cpuTex, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &sr);

    COLORREF* pPixels = (COLORREF*)sr.pData;

    rgb.rgbtRed = (pPixels[0] >> 16) & 0xff;
    rgb.rgbtGreen = (pPixels[0] >> 8) & 0xff;
    rgb.rgbtBlue = pPixels[0] & 0xff;

    D3DDeviceContextTest->Unmap(cpuTex, 0);

    cpuTex->Release();
    gpuTex->Release();

    hr = DeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();

    return rgb;
}
```

until "AcquireNextFrame" return OK my code work fine, but when return "DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT"

crash in this line:

```
hr = D3DDeviceContextTest->Map(cpuTex, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &sr);
```

So I think my is not the right way to make a copy of pointer value.

Can you please suggest me another way ?

Comment: The problem is in the preceding calls of `memcpy()` that have a first argument that is the address of a pointer - and, since the size being copied is larger than a pointer, those `memcpy()` calls tromp unrelated memory used by your program.  Since `ID3D11Texture2D` is not a "plain old data" object it should almost certainly not be copied using `memcpy()` - you'll need to read Microsoft documentation (and check your assumptions about how objects are laid out in C++) to find a sensible approach for copying one.

Comment: Beyond the pointer issue, as you found out AcquireNextFrame is not a screenshot/capture API, it's a queue where the desktop window manager copies video frames when it renders a new one. Using that to get a pixel when you need it is overkill and will not work well.

Comment: A fundamental question: Do you understand how winapi COM works? And have you ever considered doing something with your reaped `HRESULT` values besides ignoring them? The former is *critical* to using interfaces from DirectX; the latter part and parcel with proper COM error management. And fyi, the `comutil` library may make better RAII management of your COM interfaces easier to manage.

Comment: See [Microsoft Docs: Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com).